# How to put recyclerview item in bookmarks using Room database and change the icon state

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room

I'm using MVVM architecture in my news application and also using the Room database for local storage.

So I want to add a feature of bookmark in my application when the user clicks on the bookmark icon it will store the article in the Room database and also after clicking the bookmark icon I want to change the state of that icon.

So what will be the logic for this feature?

Comment: `So what will be the logic for this feature?` you already understand the logic, what you're asking for is implementation, which is too broad to ask here. show what you've tried, what's working and what isn't

Comment: I have implemented it and its working but the issue is icon state is not changing I cannot handle that.